# Can I store local dev SMTP settings in civicrm.settings.php?

Tags: civicrm.settings.php, smtp

For local development, so that I can test outgoing email safely, I use the Drupal settings.php file to store my MailHog email server settings e.g.

```
$conf['smtp_host'] = 'mail'; //Docker container
$conf['smtp_port'] = '1025'; //MailHog port
```

This way I can refresh the local database and it will immediately work in my local environment.

I cannot see an obvious way of doing this for CiviCRM?  Looking at the API explorer, I have experimented with a few things like:

```
$civicrm_setting[mailing_backend]['smtpServer']
```

But does this not seem to work.  Can this be done? It would be nice to not have to change my SMTP setting each time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use something like:

`$civicrm_setting['Mailing Preferences']['mailing_backend']['smtpPort'] = '587';`

I think the group name `'Mailing Preferences'` is obsolete and could be `'domain'`, but the above works.

You could also use the `define('CIVICRM_MAIL_LOG')` which you'll find lower down in civicrm.settings.php to dump all mail raw to a file without sending it.

Comment: Thanks so much for that - works perfectly.  Tested with ['domain'] and this works so I have used this in preference to ['Mailing Preferences'].  I need to see the results of the various HTML templated emails that go out so this is ideal.

For those using MailHog with Docker my civicrm.settings.php file now has:

$civicrm_setting['domain']['mailing_backend']['smtpPort'] = '1025'; //MailHog smtp port
$civicrm_setting['domain']['mailing_backend']['smtpServer'] = 'mail'; //Docker container
$civicrm_setting['domain']['mailing_backend']['smtpAuth'] = 0; //No auth required